# React Native - Dynamic onPress Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to `react-native` and I am running into some issues that I am not sure how to tackle.

I have components that get dynamically rendered based of some `API` data.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{    
    categoryComponents.push(
        <Card key={data[i].id}>
            <CardItem>
                <Body>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={(event) => {
                        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                        navigate('Category', { category: data[i].id });
                    }}>
                        <Text>{data[i].name + "  " + data[i].id}</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </Body>
            </CardItem>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

As you can see, I store dynamic components inside an array. Which I render to the screen:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Content style={styles.spacer}>{categoryComponents}</Content>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

The issue is that inside my `TouchableHighlight` component, the `onPress` event doesn't seem to accept the `data[i].id` variable. It throws an error saying `undefined`. However, I use it outside the `onPress` event and it is defined.

I was trying to fix this issue so I changed my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    var name = data[i].name;
    var id = data[i].id;

    categoryComponents.push(
        <Card key={id}>
            <CardItem>
                <Body>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={(event) => {
                        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                        navigate('Category', { category: id });
                    }}>
                        <Text>{name + "  " + id}</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </Body>
            </CardItem>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

As you can see, I simply store the values I will use into local variables and reference those variables instead of the `data`.

This did not fix the issue, but gave me more insight.

Now my `TouchableHighlight` components `onPress` event does accept the variable, but it only uses the last iteration of the loop assignment.

So my `id` variable is always assigned to 9 across all components inside the `TouchableHighlight`. Even though outside `onPress` event the `id` variable is changing.

Due to this issue, none of my links are dynamic. How can I have dynamic `onPress` events on a `TouchableHighlight` component?

EDIT: I use `native-base` for the components.

Comment: Why not use `FlatList` and save all the hassle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to do with React Native, it's about javascript scope and closure.

`var` declare a variable which works at `function scope`, not `block scope`.

As onPress method be called async, the `i` variable is the value after `for loop`.

change loop variable declaration from `var` to `let` will solve this problem

```
// let declare a variable works at `block scope`
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){}
```

you may want [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) as a reference.